# Solr Suggester not working for copy-field

Tags: java, solr

Solr suggester component is not working for copy filed, it works fine with the indexed field. below find my configuration and schema details

**managed-schema:**

```
 <field name="make" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="model" type="text_general"/>
<copyField source="model" dest="model_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="make" dest="make_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="*" dest="suggest_Search"/>

  <field name="suggest_Search" type="textSuggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

 <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**solrconfig**

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggest_Search</str>
    <str name="weightField">model</str> 
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>

  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

It works fine if I change the field to make or model, Please help me find where I am doing wrong

Comment: model_str field is not defined in schema...Defien the same like other fields and apply the fieldType to it

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Thanks for the replay, as I am new to Solr can you explain little more please or any example or any site to refer

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html